# Numerical solution of nonlinear convection equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, physics

I am trying to compute the numerical solution of the 2D non linear convection equation

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+u\nabla u=0 $$

I am using the technique used in this [work](https://www.duo.uio.no/bitstream/handle/10852/10896/Kalland_Master.pdf?sequence=1) at page 38-40 .

The case that under consideration is a square domain of size $2\times2$ with Dirichlet boundary condition (BC) at north and south boundaries and periodic BC for the east and west boundaries .

The initial condition is a gaussian function $u_i=exp((x-0.8)^2+(y-1)^2)$ for the two component of $u$, as shown in figure (the quantity plotted is the velocity module $|u|$)[image: Initial condition]

The problem is that during the computation there is an accumulation of the velocity magnitude around the maximum value of the velocity until there is a explosion of the simulation. 
The two following picture shows the value of u at two times during the simulation. The first at $t=0.015$ ad the second $t=0.02$
[image] 
[image]

This behaviour doesn't seem very physical to me. On the internet I am reading of the possibility of this kind of simulation of showing shock-like solution. 
The question is, is this the case ? Or it may depends on some bugs in the code ? Or a first order scheme is not suited for this kind of nonlinear equations ?

The only thing that I can say is, that is not linked to the CFL condition I have tried different to reduce the time step and the results are always the same.

Thank you for your help

Comment: How does one interpret the second term of the equation? The gradient is a 2D vector, $u$ itself a scalar valued function, as is the first term?

Comment: In your problem, the propagation speed is proportional to the amplitude, so shocks may certainly occur, though it is hard to tell if they will on such a short time-scale. You might as well be experiencing numerical instability. The thesis you are referring to doesn't seem to demonstrate that the finite difference scheme is stable. Do you have any reason to believe that it is? Try running your code with simpler initial data, e.g. a constant function or a positive linear one. If that doesn't work, you likely have a problem with your implementation.